# number of steps a random walk in a line on the nonnegative integers

Tags: probability-theory, random

let $T_n$ denote the number of steps a linear random walk on the nonnegative integers takes before reaching the position $n$ for the first time. What will be $\mathbb{E}[T_n]$.

I tried to derive this:

let say to reach "$3$" we have $\mathbb{E}[3]$ expected number of steps

= probability to getting to "number 3" in 3 steps X 3  + probability of getting to "number 3" in 5 steps X 5+ probability of getting to "number 3" in 7 steps X 7 + ...

$\mathbb{E}[T_3] = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \times 3 + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4 \times 5 + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^6 \times 7 + ...$

assuming this "Arithmetico-geometric sequence" we get answer of approx $N$.

the correct answer is $N^2$. Anyone have idea what going wrong in my analysis?

Comment: Where does the walk start and what are the probabilities?  Does it start at $1$ with equal probability of going up or down $1$?  Or does it start at $0$ with probability $1$ it goes to $1$ and then equal probability of increasing or decreasing at every other point?

Comment: @Patrick Non negative linear Random walk start at 0, and it is in straight line so it can go point 1 in first move. so the probability of going to 1 is "1" (it can't go to negative). if we are at point 1 probability of next move to  2 will be 1/2 and probability of next move to 0 will be 1/2 also. So at any point other than 0 moving left or right have same probability of 1/2

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind $\frac{1}{2^6} \times 7$?

Comment: @CalvinLin "1/2^6 × 7" represent expected value of path length when you reach  "point 3" using 7 distance.Assume you start with point 0 there is only one chose and that is to move to point 1(with probability 1).[remember this is linear random walk in non negative integer]. now you take move "0-->1-->2-->1-->2-->1-->2-->3" notice path have 7 moves each move except the first one have 1/2 probability as you can move either left or right at each point except point 0 (where you have no choice but to move right). hence the prob is 1/2^6. So the expected val = 1/2^6 * 7

Comment: Actually there are 4 paths with 7 steps: [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3], and [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]. The random walk can visit 0 as many times as you like. Notice that these 4 paths have different probabilities because of the extra zeros.

Comment: @David The point of my question, is for you to realize that you could have gone back to 0, as Byron illustrated. That is why your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x\geq 0$ define $e_x$ to be the expected number of steps needed 
to reach state $x+1$ starting at state $x$. Then $e_0=1$, and for $x>0$ 
first step analysis gives $e_x=1+(e_{x-1}+e_x)/2.$ This equation implies $e_x=2+e_{x-1}$, 
so by induction $e_x=2x+1$. Then   $$\mathbb{E}[T_n]=\sum_{x=0}^{n-1} e_x =\sum_{x=0}^{n-1} (2x+1)= n^2.$$

Comment: @Bryon thanks Got it!

Comment: Question, I don't understand why you don't get $e_x = 1\times \frac{1}{2} + \frac{e_{x-1}+e_x}{2}$. My logic would have been, with prob $1/2$ we go from $x$ to $x+1$ and so the number of steps there is 1. Otherwise, with prob $1/2$ we go back to $x-1$ and so we need to again get back to $x$ to get to $x+1$. What an I missing here?

Comment: You take one step no matter what. The second term gives the expected number of additional steps needed.

Comment: Ahh yes. My formula above should have $\frac{1+e_{x-1}+e_x}{2}$ anyway which agrees with yours. Thanks for clearing that up.